# How to tell hibernate to create Date instead of timestamp in DB?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

How can I tell hibernate that a `Date` should be created as a Date in postgres SQL database, and not as a `timestamp`?
According to www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html Date should be possible, but how?

```
@Entity
class Test {
    private java.util.Date date;
}
```

becomes:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(date timestamp without time zone)
```

Comment: I think you should use `java.sql.Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Temporal` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Temporal.html):

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
```

There are also `TIME` and `TIMESTAMP` `TemporalTypes`. `TIMESTAMP` is the default.

EDIT. You can also use one of the appropriate SQL types: `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time` or `java.sql.Timestamp`.

The DB mapping is identical, whether you use `java.util.Date` with annotations or `java.sql.*` Using `java.util.Date` gives you a consistent interface regardless of the physical DB mapping while sql types may make your intent clearer.

Comment: It is not a solution, when timestamp is used in DB than hibernate will throw exception 'Found: timestamp, expected: date'.

Comment: The annotation will not fix your existing DDL, how is it supposed to do that? But during DDL generation from JPA entities, it will tell the JPA provider to create a `DATE` column, which was OPs requirement.

Comment: @whatswrong - IMHO you have misunderstood OP's requirement and the downvote is unwarranted. Your issue is a different one, you can post a separate question for it. If you think I have misunderstood OP's, please explain.